# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (User is undefined)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm making a ReactJs app that started with Create-Repack-App --full that sets up a lot for me including the user with the Devise gem and without a need to set headers along the way. I have created a user with the typical test@test.com, etc. but I get the error in the title when I try to load my home page. I'm trying to get my home page to render conditionally depending on if the user is logged in or not.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class Home extends Component {

  homePage = () => {
    debugger 
    const { user } = this.props;
    if (user.id) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>Games</div>
          <div>Sessions</div> 
          <div>Friends</div>
          <div>Tools</div> 
          <div>Help</div>
          <div>Settings</div>
          <div>Profile</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Header as='h1' textAlign='center'>Welcome to Board Game Tracker</Header>
        <Header as='h2' textAlign='center'>Please Log In or Register</Header>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.homePage() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { user: state.user };
};

export default Home;
```

It's been a while since I started a new app from the ground up and am probably missing something extraordinarily basic.

Here is the error in full:

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
Home._this.homePage
src/components/Home.js:9
   6 | homePage = () => {
   7 |   debugger 
   8 |   const { user } = this.props;
>  9 |   if (user.id) {
  10 |     return (
  11 |       <div>
  12 |         <div>Games</div>
View compiled
Home.render
src/components/Home.js:33
  30 | render() {
  31 |   return (
  32 |     <div>
> 33 |       { this.homePage() }
  34 |     </div>
  35 |   );
  36 | }
```

And finally the terminal error:

```
Started GET "/api/auth/validate_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-18 09:22:43 -0600
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as HTML
/Users/michellegarcia/personal_projects/board_game_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant ApplicationController::NameError
/Users/michellegarcia/personal_projects/board_game_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6: warning: previous definition of NameError was here
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Api
  User Load (3.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "test@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/michellegarcia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /Users/michellegarcia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/michellegarcia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Update (1.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["tokens", "{\"8ruFDYLiKIRAhTy1Cc0tnw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$3UtLDmi5ljtUJOfKwzx.y.njRRkZiFNoyYOBi35FGL6RxkHcsBHye\",\"expiry\":1541085763,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$OiJjztMk7.bYuWxgwHKYmewx8T5xO00IM6iaLxQ/pMAsSdNwagy9W\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-10-18T09:22:43.556-06:00\"}}"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-18 15:22:43.659159"], ["id", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/michellegarcia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (8.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ /Users/michellegarcia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 200 OK in 289ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 15.1ms)


Started GET "/%3Canonymous%3E" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-18 09:22:46 -0600
Processing by StaticController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"other"=>"<anonymous>"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 186ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template Users/michellegarcia/personal_projects/board_game_app/public/index.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/michellegarcia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/templates"
  * "/Users/michellegarcia/personal_projects/board_game_app"
  * "/"
):

app/controllers/static_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Postgres is definitely on and I definitely have a user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you "console.log(this.props)?"

Comment: The code looks fine. The error you get is caused by trying to access a property of an undefined object, the user object in your case. The error is probably happening when trying to retrieve the user from your DB. This could be of several different reasons such as not waiting for your response, authentication or that the data does not exist.

Comment: @joshbang this.props would work, but I couldn't find user in it. this.State was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to connect your home component to redux store?

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: That fixed it. You are a god.

Comment: Glad I could help.